# Unlock Android with Pattern Lock Without Losing Data

Tags: usb-debugging, htc, pattern-lock

I have HTC One M7 which I wasn't using from 2018. So I forgot pattern lock but I want check data on this smartphone. It's good scope to develop and practice with Android. What I've learn till now:

- USB debugging is turn off (after use "adb devices" command phone didn't show up)
- I can't unlock bootloader because I will lose data (I don't want it)

So, there is any possible way to unlock HTC with forgotten pattern lock and without losing data? Thanks for every help!

Comment: https://github.com/bkerler/edl

Comment: I think its extremely unlikely.  I dont know if the Android phone in 2018, used to encrypt the contents.

Comment: Android Jelly Bean is not encrypted, you can just delete locksettings.db